# Grunt Copy Flatten not working as expected

Tags: gruntjs, grunt-contrib-copy

I have a directory structure as follows:

```
source/
    libraries/
        d3.js
        lodash.js
        //etc
```

I have grunt-copy setup as follows:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    files: [
      {
        src: ["source/libraries/*.js"], 
        dest: "build/", 
        flatten: true
      }
```

I expect it to flatten the output into build, so that I will have

```
build/
    d3.js
    //etc
```

Instead, I get a reproduction of the original directory structure in build:

```
build/
    source/
        libraries/
            d3.js
            //etc
```

What gives? Am I not using flatten properly?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Well, if you're only using `flatten` because you want everything in `source/libraries` to go into `build`, I would suggest actually using the `cwd` (current working directory) option instead. If, on the other hand, you actually have subfolders in `source/libraries` then you probably want that `src` line to be `source/libraries/**/*.js`.

In any case, if you can use `cwd` instead it would look like this:

```
copy: {
  main: {
    files: [
      {
        src: ["*.js"],
        dest: "build/",
        cwd: "source/libraries/"
      }
    ]
  }
```

For the other case, maybe this? (Notice the `expand` option set to `true`)

```
copy: {
  main: {
    files: [
      {
        src: ["source/libraries/**/*.js"],
        dest: "build/",
        flatten: true,
        expand: true
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

Comment: Using cwd does fix my issue. However, based on the grunt docs, it looks like flatten _should_ work too: 

    `"flatten Remove all path parts from generated dest paths."`

Do you know why it doesnt?

Comment: Did you try adding the `expand` option as well? Every time I've ever seen `flatten` I see it with `expand`.

Comment: heh... just read up on the docs... right above that line you mention is this: "`expand` Set to `true` to enable the following options:" (`flatten` is one of the "following options"). ;)