# Copying files using grunt makes all the parent directories

Tags: gruntjs

when I copy some files using the following task

```
    copy: {
        tmp: {
            src: 'lib/public/**',
            dest: 'tmp/'
        }
    }
```

this is my source

```
|_lib
    |_public
            |_ dir1
            |_ dir2
            |_ index.html
```

My directory structure from the copy method looks like the following

```
|_tmp
     |_lib
          |_public
                  |_ dir1
                  |_ dir2
                  |_ index.html
```

I'd prefer if the directory looked more like this

```
|_tmp
     |_ dir1
     |_ dir2
     |_ index.html
```

In other words I want everything from `lib/public` to be copied to `tmp` is there another option I have to enable?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Update:** to copy the contents (folders and files) without the root source directory, you can use the `cwd` option. Looks like you've discovered this based on your comments.

```
copy: {
  tmp: {
    expand: true,
    cwd: 'lib/public',
    src: '**',
    dest: 'tmp/'
  }
}
```

---

You can achieve this using the `flatten` and `filter` properties. Since you want the files without parent directories, you'll want to specify the `'isFile'` filter. To use `flatten` you'll need to enable the `expand` option. The documentation covers this and other options under the ["Building the files object dynamically"](http://gruntjs.com/configuring-tasks#building-the-files-object-dynamically) section.

Your configuration should resemble the following:

```
copy: {
  tmp: {
    expand: true,
    flatten: true,
    src: 'lib/public/**',
    dest: 'tmp/',
    filter: 'isFile'
  }
}
```

Be aware that files that share the same name will be overwritten (the deeper nested file will overwrite the ones higher up in the tree).

Comment: I edited my example to be more specific. the example you give is almost what I need but not quite. If you get a moment perhaps you can offer an alternative answer?

Comment: Actually the link you posted helped I found that what I really need to do is this              tmp: {
                expand: true,
                cwd: 'lib/public',
                src: '**',
                dest: 'tmp/'
            }

Comment: @EdgarMartinez updated. Looks like you found the solution already!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want the `flatten` option. You can read my answer to [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20752522/grunt-copy-flatten-not-working-as-expected) (not exactly a duplicate), but it's fairly simple:

```
copy: {
    tmp: {
        src: 'lib/public/**',
        dest: 'tmp/',
        flatten: true,
        expand: true
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited my example to be more specific. The example you give is almost what I need but not quite. If you get a moment perhaps you can offer an alternative answer? What I really am trying to avoid is the copying of the parent folders and just what is inside them including the directories

Comment: Aaaah... I see. Well, I think @ahmad-mageed's answer is quite thorough with the update then. Glad you figured it out.